# How to record API Ticker data in an Excel table

Tags: excel, api, store, record, ticker

I have no VBA experience so I am hoping that there is a way to do this without use of macros or programming - If there isn't then help with code and explaining what it is doing, so I can learn from it, would be very much appreciated. :)

I am using a daily refreshed API ticker which gives me a date and a value.

I then have a table predefined for the year, 01/01/18 > 31/12/18 (for example), adjacent to a cell for the value.

I’ve used vlookup to populate the value on the given day, but obviously in this current state, the data is not recordable, so when the date on the API changes from 01/01/18 to 02/01/18 the value is lost and it moves onto the next specified cell to fill.

Is there a way to record/ store this data – Make it non external automatically? Without copy/paste text or value manually?

[image: Mock up table for example]

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "API ticker." (Note that using the "API" tag is not recommended, if you hover over it.) Unless this question is about coding then it is probably off topic for SO. Review this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then revisit your question. In a nutshell, no one is going to write your code, and it looks like you are asking a programmatic question (though it is not terribly clear what you want to achieve).

Comment: Hey JDV, thanks for getting back to me.

An example of ticker is here: https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP

In this instance it updates every day with closing currency settlement values.

I was hoping to avoid code if possible and just find out if there was a way in Excel to achieve it without making it too complicated

Comment: You'll need VBA to pull this off since any formula you try to write is going to grab NULL when the date changes for the date it's set to look up. There's no way with a formula to say "If this pulled some non-null value yesterday, but today it only finds null for this date, then use the previous non-null value you found". The VBA to do this would probably just grab the data from the API (or wait for you to paste it in) and then append the date/value to a table to record it forever. Each time a new value hits, it just pastes it at the end of the list.

Comment: Yeah, to backup what @JNevill said, all the solutions out there use VBA and a button to fetch from whatever ticker source you need.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are fetching from that API is JSON. Unfortunately support for JSON in VBA is 100% non-existent. There are some folks that have made some libraries, but since you are new to VBA, and the JSON response is very very small, I think it's best to just treat the response from the API as a string and get the stuff we need by parsing the string.

An example of what this would look like for that URL (appending whatever is fetched to Sheet1 columns A, B, C, and D:

```
Sub getTickerValue()

    'Get the data from the API
    Dim strResponse As String: strResponse = LoadHTML("https://api.fixer.io/latest?symbols=USD,GBP")

    'Since we aren't actually going to parse the json because it's not well supported in VBA
    '   we will instead remove everything we don't care about and parse the results
    '   So replace out double quotes and squirrely braces (Not a great idea for more complex json)
    strResponse = Replace(strResponse, Chr(34), "")
    strResponse = Replace(strResponse, "}", "")
    strResponse = Replace(strResponse, "{", "")

    'Load up each item into an array splitting on comma
    Dim jsonArray As Variant: jsonArray = Split(strResponse, ",")

    'Loop the array, sniff for the data we want, and toss it in it's respective variable
    Dim strBase As String, strDate As String, strRate1 As String, strRate2 As String
    For Each elem In jsonArray
        If Split(elem, ":")(0) = "base" Then strBase = Split(elem, ":")(1)
        If Split(elem, ":")(0) = "date" Then strDate = Split(elem, ":")(1)
        If Split(elem, ":")(0) = "rates" Then strRate1 = Split(elem, ":")(2)
        If Split(elem, ":")(0) = "USD" Then strRate2 = Split(elem, ":")(1)
    Next elem

    'Set up the range where we will output this by starting at cell A99999
    '   in Sheet1 and going up until we hit the first occupied cell
    '   offset by 1 row to get the first unoccupied cell
    Dim outRange As Range
    Set outRange = Sheet1.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    'Now we know the last unoccupied cell in Sheet1, go ahead and dump the data
    outRange.Value = strBase
    outRange.Offset(, 1).Value = strDate
    outRange.Offset(, 2).Value = strRate1
    outRange.Offset(, 3).Value = strRate2


End Sub

Function LoadHTML(xmlurl) As String
  'Using the XMLHTTP library to get the results since monkeying with IE is ugly and painful
  Dim xmlhttp

  Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
  xmlhttp.Open "GET", xmlurl, False

  ' switch to manual error handling
  On Error Resume Next

  xmlhttp.Send
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo xmlhttp.parseError.Reason
    Err.Clear
  End If

  ' switch back to automatic error handling
  On Error GoTo 0

  LoadHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
End Function
```

This isn't exactly what you are looking for, but I think it's close enough to get you in the ballpark. You can run it by creating a button or shape on the sheet and then pointing that at the "GetTickerValue" macro. Alternatively after pasting this in a new VBA Module you can stick your cursor in the `GetTicketValue` block of code and hitting the play button at the top (or F5). It will fetch the data and append it to whatever your Sheet1 is.